# Listbox - Unable to recognize blank value

Tags: vba, excel

I have two listboxes in my script which are populated with Month values and Year values.  If the listbox is populated with values, it writes them to a worksheet, whereas if they are blank, it should throw an error.

I created a test scenario where I have two blank listboxes, the code below should throw a message box advising the user to select a value before executing the script.  However, VBA has a mind of its own and thinks that the list boxes are populated with values, therefore I get:

> Runtime Error 1004 - Unable to get the List property of the DropDown class

Is there something wrong with the code below that I am not seeing?

```
Sub TestDropDown()
Dim MonthBox As DropDown, YearBox As DropDown
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS4 as Worksheet

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS4 = WB.Worksheets("Config")

Set MonthBox = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Sheet").DropDowns("Drop Down 8")
Set YearBox = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Sheet").DropDowns("Drop Down 9")

'Check Monthbox for values
If IsNull(MonthBox.Value) Then
   MsgBox ("Select a Month before running the script")
   Failvalue = 1
   GoTo EndSub:
Else
   WS4.Cells(2, 9).Value = MonthBox.List(MonthBox.Value)
End If

'Check Yearbox for values
If IsNull(YearBox.Value) Then
   MsgBox "Please select a Year before running the script", vbExclamation
   Failvalue = 1
   GoTo EndSub:
Else
   WS4.Cells(2, 10).Value = YearBox.List(YearBox.Value)
End If


EndSub:

If Failvalue = 0 Then
   MsgBox ("Process complete")
Else
   MsgBox "Process failed to complete", vbCritical
End If

WS4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `.ListIndex` instead of the `.Value`. If ListIndex returns zero, it means none is selected.

Try this:

```
Sub TestDropDown()
    Dim MonthBox As DropDown, YearBox As DropDown, Failvalue As Integer
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS4 As Worksheet

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set WS4 = WB.Worksheets("Config")

    Set MonthBox = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Sheet").DropDowns("Drop Down 8")
    Set YearBox = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Sheet").DropDowns("Drop Down 9")

    'Check Monthbox for values
    'If IsNull(MonthBox.Value) Then
    If MonthBox.ListIndex = 0 Then
       MsgBox ("Select a Month before running the script")
       Failvalue = 1
       GoTo EndSub:
    Else
       WS4.Cells(2, 9).Value = MonthBox.List(MonthBox.ListIndex)
    End If

    'Check Yearbox for values
    'If IsNull(YearBox.Value) Then
    If YearBox.ListIndex = 0 Then
       MsgBox "Please select a Year before running the script", vbExclamation
       Failvalue = 1
       GoTo EndSub:
    Else
       WS4.Cells(2, 10).Value = YearBox.List(YearBox.ListIndex)
    End If

EndSub:

    If Failvalue = 0 Then
       MsgBox ("Process complete")
    Else
       MsgBox "Process failed to complete", vbCritical
    End If

    WS4.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the following line of code wasn't sufficent as the listbox value wasn't equating to null.

```
If IsNull(YearBox.Value) then
```

If a ran a msgbox on the listbox value, it was returning 0 on a blank listbox so I changed the code to the following

```
If YearBox.Value = 0 then
```

This works fine!